# Blazor application shows error in console when Auto mode is used

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0

I used Visual Studio latest preview with .NET8 RC1 to build a new Blazor App that allows Client and Server interactive components. By default, the app has its default rendering mode which I think is SSR.

In order to switch to the Auto mode, I used the following code as suggested by Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

So I have this:

```
    <Routes @rendermode="@RenderMode.Auto"/>
```

in my App.razor file.

Although the app runs, I see this error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Root component type 'BlazorApp9.Components.Routes' could not be found in the assembly 'BlazorApp9'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer.<UpdateRootComponents>g__AddRootComponent|8_0(RootComponentOperation operation)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer.UpdateRootComponents(String operationsJson)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.WebRenderer.WebRendererInteropMethods.UpdateRootComponents(String operationsJson)
   at
```

If I use RenderMode.Server, I dont see this error.

I have not changed any code to the template provided by Visual Studio.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Any interactive components (which is what you are making `Routes` by setting its `RenderMode` to `Auto`) must be moved to the webassembly/client project in RC1.

This is required because `Routes` must now be built in WASM and sent to the browser as part of the webassembly bits.

Comment: I saw your answer. I have a similar issue but in a Blazor component. If a Razor page in a Blazor component, has a dependency on a component in the same project that requires to use the `rendermode`, how can I resolve the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77645996/net8-blazor-components-and-render-mode